# Fedora 29 4.20.4-200.fc29 bluetooth.service: Failed to set up mount namespacing

Tags: linux, fedora, bluetooth

I am unable to use Bluetooth on Fedora 29 with the rt8822be driver with an Asus z370e ROG Strix motherboard. Bluetooth fails to start, as you can see in the logs below. I would very much appreciate any help because my google-fu is unable to solve this problem thus far.

Here is some of the latest lines of output from journalctl  -r -u bluetooth

```
-- Reboot --
Dec 03 09:20:06 DESKTOP-DK3GANT systemd[1]: Stopped Bluetooth service.
Dec 03 09:20:06 DESKTOP-DK3GANT bluetoothd[1032]: Exit
Dec 03 09:20:06 DESKTOP-DK3GANT bluetoothd[1032]: Stopping SDP server
Dec 03 09:20:06 DESKTOP-DK3GANT bluetoothd[1032]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.49 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Dec 03 09:20:06 DESKTOP-DK3GANT bluetoothd[1032]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.49 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Dec 03 09:20:06 DESKTOP-DK3GANT systemd[1]: Stopping Bluetooth service...
Dec 03 09:20:06 DESKTOP-DK3GANT bluetoothd[1032]: Terminating
Dec 03 09:18:53 DESKTOP-DK3GANT bluetoothd[1032]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.49 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Dec 03 09:18:53 DESKTOP-DK3GANT bluetoothd[1032]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.49 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Dec 03 09:18:38 localhost.localdomain bluetoothd[1032]: Bluetooth management interface 1.14 initialized
Dec 03 09:18:38 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Dec 03 09:18:38 localhost.localdomain bluetoothd[1032]: Starting SDP server
Dec 03 09:18:38 localhost.localdomain bluetoothd[1032]: Bluetooth daemon 5.50
Dec 03 09:18:38 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
-- Reboot --
Dec 03 09:17:58 DESKTOP-DK3GANT systemd[1]: Stopped Bluetooth service.
Dec 03 09:17:57 DESKTOP-DK3GANT bluetoothd[1105]: Exit
Dec 03 09:17:57 DESKTOP-DK3GANT bluetoothd[1105]: Stopping SDP server
Dec 03 09:17:57 DESKTOP-DK3GANT bluetoothd[1105]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.218 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Dec 03 09:17:57 DESKTOP-DK3GANT systemd[1]: Stopping Bluetooth service...
Dec 03 09:17:57 DESKTOP-DK3GANT bluetoothd[1105]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.218 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Dec 03 09:17:57 DESKTOP-DK3GANT bluetoothd[1105]: Terminating
Dec 03 08:54:36 DESKTOP-DK3GANT bluetoothd[1105]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.218 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Dec 03 08:54:36 DESKTOP-DK3GANT bluetoothd[1105]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.218 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Dec 03 08:54:16 localhost.localdomain bluetoothd[1105]: Bluetooth management interface 1.14 initialized
Dec 03 08:54:16 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Dec 03 08:54:16 localhost.localdomain bluetoothd[1105]: Starting SDP server
Dec 03 08:54:16 localhost.localdomain bluetoothd[1105]: Bluetooth daemon 5.50
Dec 03 08:54:16 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
-- Reboot --
Dec 03 08:53:31 DESKTOP-DK3GANT systemd[1]: Stopped Bluetooth service.
Dec 03 08:53:31 DESKTOP-DK3GANT bluetoothd[1037]: Exit
Dec 03 08:53:31 DESKTOP-DK3GANT bluetoothd[1037]: Stopping SDP server
Dec 03 08:53:31 DESKTOP-DK3GANT bluetoothd[1037]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.377 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Dec 03 08:53:31 DESKTOP-DK3GANT bluetoothd[1037]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.377 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Dec 03 08:53:31 DESKTOP-DK3GANT bluetoothd[1037]: Terminating
Dec 03 08:53:31 DESKTOP-DK3GANT systemd[1]: Stopping Bluetooth service...
Dec 03 08:53:31 DESKTOP-DK3GANT bluetoothd[1037]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.90 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Dec 03 08:53:31 DESKTOP-DK3GANT bluetoothd[1037]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.90 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Dec 03 08:26:11 localhost.localdomain bluetoothd[1037]: RFCOMM server failed for :1.377/Profile/HSPHSProfile/00001108-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb: rfcomm_bind: Address already in use (98)
Dec 03 08:26:11 localhost.localdomain bluetoothd[1037]: RFCOMM server failed for Headset Voice gateway: rfcomm_bind: Address already in use (98)
Dec 03 08:26:11 localhost.localdomain bluetoothd[1037]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.377 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Dec 03 08:26:11 localhost.localdomain bluetoothd[1037]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.377 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Dec 03 08:23:10 localhost.localdomain bluetoothd[1037]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.90 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Dec 03 08:23:10 localhost.localdomain bluetoothd[1037]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.90 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Dec 03 08:23:08 localhost.localdomain bluetoothd[1037]: Bluetooth management interface 1.14 initialized
Dec 03 08:23:08 localhost.localdomain bluetoothd[1037]: Starting SDP server
Dec 03 08:23:08 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Dec 03 08:23:08 localhost.localdomain bluetoothd[1037]: Bluetooth daemon 5.50
Dec 03 08:23:08 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
```

Here is output from running sudo systemctl status bluetooth.service.

```
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2019-02-20 20:51:47 EST; 16s ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
  Process: 12926 ExecStart=/usr/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd (code=exited, status=226/NAMESPACE)
 Main PID: 12926 (code=exited, status=226/NAMESPACE)

Feb 20 20:51:47 fedora systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Feb 20 20:51:47 fedora systemd[12926]: bluetooth.service: Failed to set up mount namespacing: No such file or directory
Feb 20 20:51:47 fedora systemd[12926]: bluetooth.service: Failed at step NAMESPACE spawning /usr/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd: No such file or directory
Feb 20 20:51:47 fedora systemd[1]: bluetooth.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=226/NAMESPACE
Feb 20 20:51:47 fedora systemd[1]: bluetooth.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 20 20:51:47 fedora systemd[1]: Failed to start Bluetooth service.
```

I have been searching the internet for errors having to do with "Failed to set up mount namespacing", but I don't see many questions asked about it.

Here is some output from sudo rfkill list all

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Here is output from running sudo hciconfig hci0

```
hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 80:C5:F2:63:90:9C  ACL MTU: 1021:8  SCO MTU: 255:16
    DOWN 
    RX bytes:2322 acl:0 sco:0 events:151 errors:0
    TX bytes:21362 acl:0 sco:0 commands:151 errors:0
```

Thank you for any and all help rendered.
Cody

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by running `sudo dnf reinstall bluez` and then `sudo systemctl start bluetooth`.

Answer (score 0):

On Debian unstable, the upgrade from bluez 5.64-1 to 5.64-2 fixed the problem.